# Jmeter - While Controller with Counter Config Element

Tags: performance, testing, while-loop, jmeter, counter

I have a while controller that waits for a certain regular expression to appear in the response before logging the user out. However, due to timeouts with the previous request this will occasionally enter into an infinite loop, skewing the data. I'm looking to set this request so that it only sends 5 times before exiting the loop and logging the user out.

After searching for an answer it seems that either the ${__counter()} variable or Counter Config Element are the solution, but neither seem to be working as I would expect.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
While Controller (${__javaScript( "${DONE_A}" != "Thank you for your order" || ${counter} < 5;)}  
    Counter (set to 5, increment 1)  
    Constant Timer (2000 ms)  
    GET /checkout/confirmation  
    ^RegExp Extractor (DONE)

Logout
```

Comment: Have you used a debug sampler to be sure your variables are being set?

Comment: Yes, Counter variable increments for each iteration of while loop. It just doesn't exit

Answer (score 4):

I can see a couple of problems with your script:

1. During 1st iteration counter value is `NaN`, you need to either declare it via i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1932303-using-user-defined-variables) or to add check for "Not a Number" into your condition
2. You cannot refer variables as `${counter}` in __JavaScript function. If you need to address it, you need to surround the variable with quotation marks (like you do for your `DONE_A` variable. If you need to treat the variable like a numeric one - use i.e. [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function

Given point 2, my expectation is what your While controller clause simply does not work, that's why you're getting an endless loop.

This one should be good for your scenario:

```
${__javaScript(isNaN(parseInt("${counter}")) || parseInt("${counter}") < 5 && "${DONE_A}" != "Thank you for your order",)}
```

Comment: Stack trace on first iteration was driving me nuts..  all internet examples don't mention isNaN on first iteration or parseInt.  Cheers